# Assistance, tips and guidelines for converting Matlab code to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am a heavy Matlab programmer and need to accomplish a task which Matlab can't do natively. For this purpose, I have chosen Python. I have completed the Codecademy Python course and am going through Zed Shaw's *Learn Python the Hard Way*. Also, I have familiarized myself with NumPy and SciPy.

Over the last week, I have tried almost everything from Matlab-to-Python converters to interfaces between Matlab and Python. I have also spent a lot of time coding directly in Python. But I just haven't been able to get anything to work. Given my Matlab code, I will provide a list of areas with which I am struggling.

Matlab code: http://pastebin.com/4tkne94Z

**What this code does:** It solves a general system of ordinary differential equations and outputs a graph. The input parameter N to the outer function Array specifies the number of ODEs in the system, with N being an even number. (The ODEs are defined using summation notation and indexed accordingly. That is why they are generalizable.)

**Goal of using Python:** To run a script that loops over N ranging from 2 to 1000, in steps of 2. This would be almost impossible with Matlab due to its overhead, but feasible in Python (especially given that I have access to a supercomputing cluster).

**Issues with translation:** I am comfortable with Python syntax. But not so much with functions, including outer, inner, and nested ones. Thus my attempts at translation have been futile.

1. How can I define the functions in the code accordingly in Python?
2. Where should I incorporate the main for loop running over series?
3. Lastly, I'm not sure how to define global variables properly in Python!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As written, your question is very broad. You ask three questions, each of which would require a long answer. Also, you do not show us what you've tired in Python. I suggest you look through the [how-to-ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, break up your question into smaller questions when you get stuck. Last, SO prefers you post code directly to SO and not on 3rd party sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience in matlab is limited, but here's my input based off of looking at your code

1. I would define EqnsArray outside of the main function and add N as one of the arguments.
2. I don't see how this would need to change if what you have works in matlab
3. Based off of what I see I don't think you need to declare anything as global. Any variable encountered inside of a function that isn't defined within the function will be assumed to be a global variable in python.